# Shopware 6 Admin api: How to store a new entity with a default entity prop

Tags: vue.js, plugins, shopware6

How to set a default value for a new entity property (like defaultCurrency.id) [within the sw-entity-single-select ***before*** `this.repository.save()`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/4b85cd419b4d4d3d6a40fde944b62799e30ca740/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/form/select/entity/sw-entity-single-select/index.js#L542)?
Is it posible? Or only after `save()` and with a new request listen on `emitted event change()`?

[Overriding createNewEntity()](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/4b85cd419b4d4d3d6a40fde944b62799e30ca740/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/form/select/entity/sw-entity-single-select/index.js#L538) does store the property value in my db...

```
...
createNewEntity() {
    const entity = this.repository.create(this.context);
    entity.name = this.newEntityName;
    entity.currencyId = this.defaultCurrency.id;
    
   ... 
}
```

...but the `debug.utils.js` response with an error (rare, because the enity is created):
`[Only Entities with "name" as the only required field are creatable.]`

Answer (score 2):

```js
createNewEntity() {
    const entity = this.repository.create(this.context);
    entity.name = this.newEntityName;
    entity.currencyId = this.defaultCurrency.id;
    
   ... 
}
```

In theory this should've already worked, given you also copied the rest of the original method. Did you check the network tab of your developer tools to look at the response of the accompanying request to `POST /api/{entity}`? That request should've failed and given a more detailed error message in the response. Could be that there are more required fields than just the `currencyId`.

Generally speaking you've got the right idea to override the component. Unfortunately it's a little tricky to do so without duplicating the entirety of the `createNewEntity` method.

I had a quick go at creating an override that decorates the repository's `create` method to modify the entity immediately after creation.

```js
Component.override('sw-entity-single-select', {
    props: {
        additionalCreationProperties: {
            type: Object,
            required: false,
            default() {
                return {};
            },
        },
    },

    computed: {
        repository() {
            const repository = this.$super('repository');
            const that = this;
            const decorator = {
                create(context, id) {
                    const entity = super.create(context, id);

                    Object.entries(that.additionalCreationProperties).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        that.$set(entity, key, value);
                    });

                    return entity;
                },
            };

            Object.setPrototypeOf(decorator, repository);

            return decorator;
        },
    }
});
```

This introduces a new property `additionalCreationProperties` that you can then use with `sw-entity-single-select` to provide default values for the created entity.

```
<sw-entity-single-select
    entity="entity"
    allow-entity-creation
    :additional-creation-properties="{ currencyId: defaultCurrency.id }"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, i `extend()` the `sw-entity-single-select` instead of `override()`. As i understand, this configuration avoid unexpected override `sw-entity-single-select` in child component/s. If i wrong, please advise me.

```
...
Component.extend('custom-entity-single-select','sw-entity-single-select', {
    ...
}
```

Then

> Did you check the network tab of your developer tools to look at the response of the accompanying request to POST /api/{entity}? That request should've failed and given a more detailed error message in the response.

There is no network notification about

After debug to find out, where the error come from (without go deeper seeking why), the [`this.$emit('option-select', ...);` in `createNewEntity()`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/2683b4c939843e061741661c4e2d7635dc13b910/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/form/select/entity/sw-entity-single-select/index.js#L542) was disabled in extended component:

```
...
Component.extend('custom-entity-single-select','sw-entity-single-select', {
    ...
    createNewEntity() {
        const entity = this.repository.create(this.context);
        entity.name = this.newEntityName;
        entity.currencyId = this.defaultCurrency.id;

        this.repository.save(entity, this.context).then(() => {
            this.lastSelection = entity;
            this.$emit('change', entity.id, entity);
                
            // this.$emit('option-select', Utils.string.camelCase(this.entity), entity);
            this.createNotificationSuccess({
                message: this.$tc(
                    'global.sw-single-select.labelEntityAddedSuccess',
                    0,
                    {
                        term: entity.name,
                        entity: this.entityCreationLabel,
                    },
                ),
            });
        }).catch(() => {
            this.createNotificationError({
                message: this.$tc('global.notification.notificationSaveErrorMessage', 0, { entityName: this.entity }),
                });
                Shopware.Utils.debug.error('Only Entities with "name" as the only required field are creatable.');
                this.isLoading = false;
            });        
    }

}
```